# How to get the features selected by the RandomizedSearchCV for LGBMClassifier model?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, lightgbm

I'm using the RandomizedSearchCV (sklearn) model selection to find out the best fit for a LightGBM LGBMClassifier model, but I'm facing issues to figure out which features has been selected for that.
I can print out the the importance of each one by:

```
lgbm_clf = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',....
lgbm_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
importance_type = lgbm_clf.importance_type
lgbm_clf.importance_type = "gain"
gain = lgbm_clf.feature_importances_
lgbm_clf.importance_type = "split"
split = lgbm_clf.feature_importances_
lgbm_clf.importance_type = importance_type

feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(snp=data.columns, zgain=zscore(gain), zsplit=zscore(split))
)
feature_importance
```

But how do I know which features has been used in the model?

e.g.: If I try:

```
lgbm.plot_split_value_histogram(lgbm_clf, 1)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: Cannot plot split value histogram, because feature 1 was not used in splitting`

This question is part of a broad doubt that has been asked at [How to compare feature selection regression-based algorithm with tree-based algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417647/how-to-compare-feature-selection-regression-based-algorithm-with-tree-based-algo).

Thank you!